# Unable to loop through Bash array of strings

Tags: arrays, bash, command-line

Recently I have been programming a small Bash file containing code to run. This is for someone's school project where they need to read through a Spanish excerpt and answer questions on it; the problem is that the assignment is in almost fluent Spanish, they can't speak fluent Spanish: they need to type it into Google Translate for this. However, this takes *quite* a long time.

Anyways, I initially solved the problem by running it through Google Tesseract (an OCR engine by... Google), printing the results using `cat`, and copy-pasting them into Google Translate. Messy, but it got the job done. Another friend heard about this and wanted to use it, but the current method wasn't going to work as it required too much computer knowledge for their level; that's how I got here.

This is my code (note: the assignment is called "Tumba"):

```sh
validtcpdfs=() # define array for valid PDF files

if [[ $1 == "-h" ]] || [[ $1 == "--help" ]]; then # if the second (first command line) argument is "-h" or "--help" print a short error message
  echo "Help:"
  echo "Place the Tumba cap [number].pdf in the current directory"
  echo "This script will complete the rest"
  exit # quit script execution
fi

for file in *; do # for all the files in the current folder
  match=$(grep -o "Tumba cap [[:digit:]]*\.pdf" <<< "$file") # $match = matched text of regex Tumba cap \d*\.pdf
  [[ ${#match} -eq ${#file} ]] && validtcpdfs+=$file # push to array if matched text's length is the same as nonmatched text's length; essentially is the file valid?
done

# for ((i=0;i<${#validtcpdfs[@]};++i)); do   #
#   printf "On tumba %s" "$validtcpdfs[$i]"  # Nonworking loop
# done                                       #

for i in "${!validtcpdfs[@]}"; do            #
  printf 'On tumba %s\n' "${validtcpdfs[i]}" # _Also_ nonworking loop
done                                         #

... code for converting ...
```

The loops (both should do the same thing and print the same bad output) don't produce the correct output. With a folder containing `Tumba cap 7.pdf` and `Tumba cap 8.pdf`, it should print

```
On tumba Tumba cap 7.pdf
On tumba Tumba cap 8.pdf
```

however it prints

```
On tumba Tumba cap 7.pdfTumba cap 8.pdf
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: `validtcpdfs+=$file` is not what you think it is/does, you're building a variable with lots of values. change it to `validtcpdfs+=("$file")` and see if it does what you wanted, but that is just a start, need to debug more, try https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Well that start solved my question. Thanks for referring the additional resource that I could use as well!

Comment: When you get to problems that shellcheck.net can't solve for you, then you'll need to be aware of the shell debug mode, using `set -x` and `set +x` surrounding problem lines of code. This will show you an unambiguous rendition of the data that is being processed. the `^M` char (DOS carriage return) is displayed as `$'\r'` for example. And you will see the values of your variables. Good luck.